# Scheme programming sum function overloading

Tags: sum, scheme, overloading

Define a function `sum`, which takes two numbers, or two real functions, and returns their *sum*. E.g.

```
(sum 1 2) => 3
((sum cos exp) 0) => 2
```

I get that for the sum of two numbers the code would be the following:

```
(define sum (lambda (x y)
  (+ x y)))
```

But what would be the code for the two real functions...? How would I do this? can anyone please help?

Also how would I do this:

> Define a function `sum-all` which works like `sum`, but works on a *list* of numbers or a *list* of functions. Assume the list contains at least one element. 
>    E.g.
>
> ```
> (sum-all (list 1 2 3)) => 6
>
> ((sum-all (list cos sin exp)) 0) => 2
> ```

Note: this is not homework... I was going through a past midterm.

Comment: the function that I tried with is posted above: 

(define sum(lambda (x y)
  (+ x y)))

Comment: for `((sum cos exp) 0)` to work `sum` would need to be `(lambda (f g) (lambda (v) (+ (f v) (g v))))` to combine this with the other sum function `(lambda (a b) (+ a b))` you'd need to look at the types of the arguments and decide what to do with them.

Comment: `(define sum (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))` is nearly equivalent to `(define sum +)`.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question, I'll have to agree with PJ.Hades that this is the simplest solution:

```
(define (sum x y)
  (if (and (number? x) (number? y))
      (+ x y)
      (lambda (n)
        (+ (x n) (y n)))))
```

For the second part, we can make good use of higher-order procedures for writing a simple solution that is a generalization of the previous one:

```
(define (sum-all lst)
  (if (andmap number? lst)
      (apply + lst)
      (lambda (n)
        (apply + (map (lambda (f) (f n)) lst)))))
```

In both procedures, I'm assuming that all the operands are of the same kind: they're either all-numbers or all-functions, as inferred from the sample code provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
(define (sum a b)
    (if (and (number? a) (number? b))
        (+ a b)
        (lambda (x)
            (+ (a x) (b x)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (sum lst)

       (cond 

         [(empty? lst) 0]

         [else (foldr + 0 lst)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((lambda (a b) (+ a b)) 4 5)
```

this how it is done using `lambda`.

using `define` we can write as follows

```
(define (sum a b) (+ a b))
```

Comment: hi, you can always edit your answer, to join the two answers together, and then delete the other one. I've edited it for you and included the second answer here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little rusty with my Scheme, so perhaps there's a better way to do this, but you could do:

```
(define (sum-all lst)
  (define (sum-funcs-helper funcs x)
    (if (empty? funcs)
        0
        (+ ((car funcs) x)
           (sum-funcs-helper (cdr funcs) x))))
  (if (empty? lst)
      0 ;; Beats me what this is supposed to return.
      (if (number? (car lst))
          (apply + lst)
          (lambda (x) (sum-funcs-helper lst x)))))
```